# not able to display full items in tkinter listbox

Tags: python, tkinter

**CODE**

```
from tkinter import *
top = Tk()
with open('new.txt' ,'r') as f:
          for index,lines in enumerate(f):
                    Lb1 = Listbox(top)
                    Lb1.insert(index, lines)
                    print(index,lines)
Lb1.pack()
top.mainloop()
```

**I want this code display all items like print statment**

Answer (score 1):

You should not create a new `Listbox` for each line of the file.

```
from tkinter import *

top = Tk()

lb = Listbox(top, width=100, height=40)
lb.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)

sb = Scrollbar(top, orient=VERTICAL, command=lb.yview)
sb.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

lb.config(yscrollcommand=sb.set)

with open('new.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        lb.insert(END, line)

top.mainloop()
```